# react native how you identify the user?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Do you save the User ID in a react state ? Or is that attack surface ?

How you identify the user in your app?

Comment: That depends on whether you want the user to be authenticated against a server or you just want local, device profiles.

Comment: To fetch the data about the user maybe likes,follower etc I need an ID but IDK where to store the user id,

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly you already have a login service, you just want to store user data to persist in the app. If so you can use the `async-storage` lib:

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/

Pretty easy to install and setUp, after that just save the data you want to persist and get in the next session, somethin like this:

```
// Saving
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

and

```
// Retriving
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

You can get more information in the link I've shared above.

Something I want to point out is that even if you have this info cached it's nice to validate the signed user on each session (using a local token for example)